# attempting to use MySQL trigger command to skip lines conditionally, ending up with empty table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to read in a table from a CSV file, and skip lines where the 'Player' field contains character string: 'Player'. I used a trigger to try to skip these lines when reading in the data, however, when I run the load data command, I end up with an empty table. Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_test
BEFORE INSERT ON player_totals 
FOR EACH ROW
    IF NEW.Player = 'Player' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'basketball-reference duplicate header';
    END IF; $$

DELIMITER ;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "leagues_NBA_2003_totals_totals.csv"
INTO TABLE player_totals
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 2 LINES;
```

I am not exactly sure what is going wrong here. When the load data command is run without the trigger it works fine, so I'm pretty sure the problem is associated with the trigger. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have a bit of ambiguity in your question:`where the 'Player' field contains character string: 'Player'` contains and equal to are not the same

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MySQL specifically, but triggers are usually used to validate the transaction as a whole, not a specific row, and in your case it is most likely canceling the entire transaction when you use SIGNAL.

Comment: Mihai- is there a string equals in sql? I'm not really sure how to fix it with that suggestion. I want to skip the whole line if the value in the field Player is equal to string 'Player'.

Comment: Michael Stewart- From what I've read using triggers, they suggest using this method to skip rows. I could be wrong though. Is there another way to skip individual rows?

Comment: This is the wrong approach, IMO. It's misuse of a trigger for something it's not designed to do. It would be much better to import into a temporary table, and then an insert into the final DB with a where clause that does the filtering.